# Traversing all keys of array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to traverse all the keys of the array in php

```
[Field_1] => SOME VALUE
[Field_2] => Array
    (
    )

[Field_3] => Array
    (
    )

[Field_4] => SOME VALUE
[Field_5] => Array
    (
    )

[Field_6] => Array
    (
    )

[Field_7] => SOME VALUE
[Field_8] => SOME VALUE
[Field_9] => SOME VALUE
[Field_10] => Array
    (
        [Field_10.1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key_1] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_2] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_3] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_4] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [key_5] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_6] => SOME VALUE
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key_1] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_2] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_3] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_4] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [key_5] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_6] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [key_1] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_2] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_3] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_4] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [key_5] => SOME VALUE
                        [key_6] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[Field_11] => Array
    (
    )
```

How do I traverse through all the keys and nested keys in the above array. Preferably using recursive function I want to traverse the array and find out a particular key in an array.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question you asked about earlier, about how to find `Field_10.1`?

Comment: @Barmar was the previous question deleted? I can't find it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes deleted the previous question, and add this more specific question.

Comment: @JeevanBhushetty It's preferable to clarify the question rather than delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function traverse_keys($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            echo "<p style='font-weight: bold'>{$key}</p>";
            traverse_keys($value);
        } else {
            echo "<p>{$key}</p>";
        }
    }
}

traverse_keys($arr);
```

This code prints out all the outer and inner keys. The keys that appear in bold are the parent keys of sub-arrays. Hope it helps!